# wordpress admin panel slowness issue

Tags: php, wordpress

we do have a multisite and in the Admin login, admin dashboard loading, content creation form Loading itself etc are loading very slow . Taking ~ 25 - 30 seconds.

These are the list of plugins enabled at the network level. Please assist which one might be causing performance issue. Have identified one plugin onlywire and removed it. And YoastSEO release notes suggested to upgrade, that also i did. 
Still performance issue persist. These are the plugins enabled at the netowrk level.

```
Wordpress Plugin list
========================
Akismet Anti-Spam
Allow REL= and HTML in Author Bios
Allow short user names for multi site.
Categories to Tags Converter Importer
FeedBurner FeedSmith Extend
Google XML Sitemaps
Import Users from CSV
Insert Headers and Footers
LDAP LPRM
More Privacy Options
Movable Type and TypePad Importer
Multisite Robots.txt Manager | MS Robots.txt
NextScripts: Social Networks Auto-Poster
No Category Base (WPML)
Redirection
SI Captcha Anti-Spam
Simple Local Avatars
Stop User Enumeration
Unfiltered MU
User Locker
User Role Editor
WP Dash Message
WP Super Cache
WP-Mail-SMTP
Yoast SEO
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be a hosting issue, how quickly was the Admin loading before you installed plugins / themes etc

Comment: Thanks Rich. i checked the CPU and memory, similulated Load test as well but the memory and CPU is with in limit only. Not reaching 100% or beyond 92%. If i disable all plugin then it loads very fast. Most of these plugins has admin related hooks for mdoifying menu, settings page etc.

Comment: You're welcome, ok this is a pain in the bum to do but enable one plugin at a time to discover which one is causing slow load. If you find that it is one single plugin then find an alternative.

Comment: instead of going to disable one by one and stimulate the load, if you have faced issues performance issue in any of the above plugins. Please share that detials. that might help. Because disabling plugin one by one is okay, but again simulate load to identify might takes huge time.